# Security Key Hybrid Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, domain, entra-id

**Environment**: Windows 11, Server 2016, Azure AD Free. 
**Problem**: `Your credentials could not be verified. (0xc000005f)`

I am trying to activate fido2 security key in my domain. 
The key which I am using is a Yubikey Bio Fido Edition. 
**First:** I activated fido2 in Azure AD for an test group with a test user. 
**Than**: I activated the security key for the pc on the Domain Controller via Group policy. 
**Last:** I binded the security key to my microsoft test user. 
But now when i try to logon in Windows11 to an other user via security key i get the error `Your credentials could not be verified. (0xc000005f)`. 

The domain which i am using in Azure and on the PCs user is also added in azure to custom domain. 
Did i forgot something?

Thank you for helping, 
Paul